Exposing a radiometer to light on Shabbos
May one intentionally or unintentionally expose a radiometer/radioscope (a glass bulb filled with gas that spins internal vanes if light shines on it) to sunlight (like opening a curtain), if this will cause the device to spin?
A radiometer has no electronic parts, but has 4 vanes that spin when enough light reaches it, as shown below. Scientists currently believe the reason it spins is related to the transfer of heat rather than the direct effect of photons (as of 8/14/2024 from Wikipedia).


What melacha are you concerned about?

I'm not sure, because it spins and that should seem like Melacha is happening somehow...
